# Text file processing using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to fetch particular portion from text file using spark scala
Is there any inbuilt function?
If we can do it by using regx then how to do that?

from below line data starts

```
/bin/rm: cannot unlink `/fabos/link_sbin/lscfg_test': Permission denied
Non-VF
======================
Date:
Mon Jul  8 08:48:40 CEST 2019

Time Zone:
Europe/Berlin


Version:
Kernel:     2.6.14.2
Fabric OS:  v7.4.2a
Made on:    Thu Jun 29 17:22:14 2017
Flash:      Tue Oct 10 09:27:26 2017
BootProm:   1.0.11

supportshow groups enabled:
Unknown key pm:0
 os         enabled
 exception  enabled
 port       enabled
 fabric     enabled
 services   enabled
 security   enabled
 network    enabled
 portlog    enabled
 system     enabled
 extend     disabled
 filter     disabled
 ficon      disabled
 iswitch    enabled
 asic_db    enabled
 fcip       disabled (not applicable to this platform)
 ag         enabled
 dce_hsl    enabled
```

Begin start_port_log_cmd group

```
Mon Jul  8 08:48:44 CEST 2019
portlogdump:
portlogdump        :
time         task       event   port cmd  args
-------------------------------------------------
Mon Jul  8 03:27:51 2019
03:27:51.199 FCPH       seq      13   28  00300000,00000000,00000591,00020182,00000000
03:27:51.199 PORT       Rx       11    0  c0fffffd,00fffffd,0ed10335,00000001
03:27:51.200 PORT       Tx       13   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,0ed3ffff,14000000
03:27:51.200 PORT       Rx       13    0  c0fffffd,00fffffd,0ed329ae,00000001
03:27:59.377 PORT       Rx       15   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,0336ffff,14000000
03:27:59.377 PORT       Tx       15    0  c0fffffd,00fffffd,03360ed2,00000001
03:27:59.377 FCPH       read     15   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,d0000000,00000000,03360ed2
03:27:59.377 FCPH       seq      15   28  22380000,03360ed2,0000052b,0000001c,00000000
03:28:00.468 PORT       Rx       13   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,29afffff,14000000
03:28:00.468 PORT       Tx       13    0  c0fffffd,00fffffd,29af0ed5,00000001
03:28:00.469 FCPH       read     13   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,66000000,00000000,29af0ed5
03:28:00.469 FCPH       seq      13   28  22380000,29af0ed5,0000052b,0000001c,00000000
03:28:01.197 FCPH       write    15   40  00fffffd,00fffffd,00000000,00000000,00000000
03:28:01.197 FCPH       seq      15   28  00300000,00000000,00000591,00020182,00000000
03:28:01.197 PORT       Tx       15   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,0ed4ffff,14000000
03:28:01.198 PORT       Rx       15    0  c0fffffd,00fffffd,0ed40338,00000001
03:28:09.380 PORT       Rx       11   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,033affff,14000000
03:28:09.380 PORT       Tx       11    0  c0fffffd,00fffffd,033a0ed6,00000001
03:28:09.380 FCPH       read     11   40  02fffffd,00fffffd,d5000000,00000000,033a0ed6
03:28:09.380 FCPH       seq      11   28  22380000,033a0ed6,0000052b,0000001c,00000000
```

---

Expected Output is like below.. I want data from particular line that can be anything(here from time onwords)

```
+------------+----+-----+----+---+----------------------------------------
|time        |task|event|port|cmd|args                                        
+------------+----+-----+----+---+----------------------------------------
|03:27:51.199|PORT|Rx   |11  |0  |c0fffffd,00fffffd,0ed10335,00000001         |
|03:27:51.200|PORT|Tx   |13  |40 |02fffffd,00fffffd,0ed3ffff,14000000         |
|03:27:51.200|PORT|Rx   |13  |0  |c0fffffd,00fffffd,0ed329ae,00000001         |
|03:27:59.377|PORT|Rx   |15  |40 |02fffffd,00fffffd,0336ffff,14000000         |
|03:27:59.377|PORT|Tx   |15  |0  |c0fffffd,00fffffd,03360ed2,00000001         |
```

This is sample data I want data from line starts with

```
time         task       event   port cmd  args
```

Comment: Can you share sample data.

Comment: Also, can you give me the expected output for this data.. This is still unclear

Comment: @user3391694 - first try to put your question in proper way then only can some one answer your question.

Comment: what i can understand from your question is that- you want to filter out records where it starts with date till ends with date as a Row.

Comment: Question is I want to fetch the  data from particular line that line can start from anything here in above data It starts from Time ..the data above time row should be skip and the data below time must be part of of each column till particular line as I mentioned in expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val serverData = spark.read.textFile("serverData.txt")
//get column names from raw data
scala> val schemaArr = serverData.filter(x=>x.matches("\\btime.*\\b")).collect.mkString.split("\\s+").toList
//get required data to transform
scala> val reqData = serverData.filter(x=>x.matches("^\\d.*"))
val df = reqData.map(x=>{
 val cols = x.split("\\s+") 
 (cols(0),cols(1),cols(2),cols(3),cols(4),cols(5)) 
 }).toDF(schemaArr:_*)
```

please try above regex to extract your data and go on. Hope this will help you!